# What is the SPSS equivalent of MDP's PCA?

Tags: spss, pca, python

I need to use Principal Component Analysis from Python. The MDP library offers PCA functionality, but the documentation is not very clear to me. I used previously PCA from SPSS, which offered various options for PCA (such as different rotations).

If anyone is familiar with both MDP and SPSS, please highlight the equivalent settings for PCA in SPSS to obtain similar results to PCA from MDP (mdp.nodes.PCANode() - for simplicity, let's consider default values).

Comment: FYI (because it kills me every time I see it mentioned) - "rotation" does not make any sense for PCA, and is only an nomenclature artifact that SPSS makes one utilize the `FACTOR` command to both extract principal components as well as other exploratory factor analysis approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try scikit-learn. It's great toolkit and has gorgeous documentation.

PCA: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html